# java get regex overlapping matches

Tags: java, regex

How do I get a regex match that is contained in another match?

I am trying to match a person's name followed by a city, within the same sentence. So I'm doing this:

```
String regex="(Bob|Mary)\\b[^\\.\\?!]*?\\b(Paris|London)\\b.*?[\\.\\?!]";
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher("Bob and Mary are planning to go to Paris. They want to leave before July.");
```

This will match "Bob and Mary are planning to go to Paris.", which is correct. But it does not match "Mary are planning to go to Paris.", which is actually part of the first match I mentioned. How do I get this second sub-match starting by "Mary"?

```
while (matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group());            
    }
```

results in:

```
Bob and Mary are planning to go to Paris.
```

That is correct. But I would expect an output like the following:

```
Bob and Mary are planning to go to Paris.
Mary are planning to go to Paris.
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: I am trying to get a fragment of text in which a person's name is followed by a city. The names of the people and city are known, I provide 'Mary', 'Bob' and the cities for illustration. And I need all the occurences of that. In the example, I need "Bob and Mary are planning to go to Paris." and I also need "Mary are planning to go to Paris.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
String regex = "(?=((Bob|Mary)\\b[^\\.\\?!]*?\\b(Paris|London)\\b.*?[\\.\\?!]))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern
        .matcher("Bob and Mary are planning to go to Paris. They want to leave before July.");
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

output:

```
Bob and Mary are planning to go to Paris.
Mary are planning to go to Paris.
```

---

Normally regex will consume what it will match once so it would be impossible to use same part of string in next match. To get rid of this problem we can use [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanism `(?=...)` and [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I am trying to do. Except that after matching the city, i need the rest of the sentence as well (in this case there is nothing but a dot ending the sentence.). But yes, this is the idea.

Comment: Thank you, Pshemo. I had read about look-ahead in other posts but I wasn't sure if it would also apply to my case.

Comment: Yeah, look-around is very powerful and useful mechanism. BTW I updated my answer with your original regex to contain rest of sentence. Not it should be OK :)

Comment: Perhaps you can help me out with a similar case. Imagine the text is "Bob and mary are planning to go to Paris and then to London". Is it possible to make the four matches, namely "Bob and Mary are planning to go to Paris", "Mary are planning to go to Paris", "Bob and Mary are planning to go to Paris and then to London" and "Mary are planning to go to Paris and then to London".

I've been trying, unsuccesfully, to combine loohahead(as per your answer) and lookbehind.
Is it possible? what would the regex be in this case?
Thanks!

Comment: @juancito I am afraid that it may be impossible to achieve this kind of matches with only regex. Maybe try to use regex to find positions of tokens that you want to find (Names, Cities) and then use other algorithm to create substrings like from(Name1,City1), from(Name1,City2), [...] , from(Name1,CityN), from (name2, City1), from(Name2,City2), [...], from(Name2,CityN), [...] from(NameM,CityN).

Comment: @Phsemo, thank you for the response. Yes, I feared it would be rather difficult. I appreciate your suggestions anyway. I'll think of something... Have a good day!

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use regex like this as well :

```
String s = "Bob and Mary are planning to go to Paris. They want to leave before July.";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Bob|Mary).*Paris");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        int i = 0;
        while(m.find(i)) { // set start index for "find"
            System.out.println(m.group());
            i = m.start() + 1; // update start index to start from beginning of last match + 1
        }
    }
```

O/P :

```
Bob and Mary are planning to go to Paris
Mary are planning to go to Paris
```