# How to use regular expression to match all possible situations in one string?

Tags: java, regex

For example,there is a string "aaaaaaa". I want to use "aaa" to get all the matches. In this string, there are like five "aaa". But using the way like this can only get two matches.

```
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("aaa");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("aaaaaaa");
while(m.find()){
            ...
}
```

Comment: Because once consumed those characters cannot be reconsumed in regex engine. So there exists only 2 matches `in aaaaaaa`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896188/java-get-regex-overlapping-matches

Answer (score 5):

You can use lookahead to get all 5 matches:

```
(?=(aaa))
```

[Lookahead is **zero-width assertion**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that regex can use to match without consuming matched patterns.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tE3oY8/2)

Comment: Hi, @anubhava Do you know a demo page that is based on Java and not in JavaScript? BTW +1

Comment: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html is there but not as good as regex101 (btw it has PCRE, Python and Javascript flavors)